# Namespaces are changing from parent to child tag in mule 3.8.4 after ttransform message

Tags: xml, namespaces, dataweave

I am having issue with namespaces in mule. Suppose I have a below xml, which after passes through transform message component, namespace is changing from parent tag to child tag. What should I do if my message has to remain as it is

````
Input:
    ```
    **<root>
    <abc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/.." xsi:type="q1:asdf" xmlns:q1="http://www.asd.com/asd/length" >
    <q1:key>aaa</q1:key>
    </abc>
    </root>
    ```

    Output:
    ```
    <root>
    <abc xsi:type="q1:asdf"  >
    <q1:key xmlns:q1="http://www.asd.com/asd/length">aaa</q1:key>
    </abc>
    </root>**

    ```
   
Here in `<abc xsi:type="q1:asdf">` the q1 namespace declaration moved to child tag  key. For which I am getting error? can you please help how to retain the  message as it is. And one more thing there is no guarantee that i get the same input message always, it changes dynamically. Only for this input I am getting issue.
````

Answer (score 0):

The Transform Message component, which is implemented using the DataWeave language, outputs the namespace definition on first usage of an element. This is completely compliant with the standard and should not cause any issues, with any standard parser. If you want to emit the namespace in a parent element, you will have to create a dummy attribute (ie `@(q1#dummy: '')`) that uses it in that element.

I'm not sure if `xsi:type="q1:asdf"` actually requires the definition at the same level of usage.

If you having an error processing that output then it is OK. If you are having an error because some other application expects the namespace in a parent, it would seem a bug of that application's XML parser. The only case that could be a bug is if the `xsi:type` causes some error because it is missing the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Can you please give link to any documentation for standard refernce please

Comment: You can see above scenario described at https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/DataWeave-generate-namespace-declarations-at-the-root-level-of-the-output-XML

Comment: Thanks, for your help. But why the namespace in attribute value is not being recognized

Comment: Actually the xmlns:q1 declaration  in the input <abc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/.." xsi:type="q1:asdf" xmlns:q1="http://www.asd.com/asd/length" >  is going to the child tag q1:key .

Comment: when the output is being processed by the target system, it is throwing error because  for  <abc xsi:type="q1:asdf" >  the namespace q1 declaration is not there in the parent tag

Comment: Please help me how to avoid namespace declaration going from parent tag to child tag